# Circular dependency in Scala collections

Tags: scala, scala-collections, circular-dependency

Trait `Traversable` has methods such as `toList`, `toMap`, `ToSeq`. Given that `List`, `Map`, `Seq` are subclasses of `Traversable`, this creates a circular dependency, which is *generally* not a desirable design pattern.

I understand that this is constrained to the collections library and it provides some nice transformation methods.

Was there any alternative design considered? Such as a "utility" class, or adding the conversion methods to `Predef`?

Say I want to add a new class: `class RandomList extends List {...}`. It would be nice to have a method `toRandomList` available for all Traversable classes, but for that I would need to "pimp my library" with an implicit on Traversable? This seems a bit of an overkill. With a utility class design, I could just extend that class (or Predef) to add my conversion method. What would be the recommended design here?

Comment: Thanks @retronym and Daniel. However, I am mainly looking for an answer to the first part of the question. Is circular dependency tacitly accepted as a design pattern in Scala libraries?

Comment: Adrian: Yes. Andrey's answer is correct.

Comment: There is a valid case about the Scala collections being a self-contained module, and therefore being "allowed" to have circular dependencies. However, it's a -big- module, and it's actively developed, therefore a cleaner design would be good. This is somewhat similar to the approach of functional programming from the outside, with imperative code on the inside (in private methods). My guess is that avoiding circular dependency would require abstracting over types (i.e. passing classes to a method like to(T) , instead of toList(), toMap(), etc), which Scala does not (yet?) support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative and extensible approach would be `to[List]`, `to[RandomList]`.

It's a bit tricky to add this with implicits, though. https://gist.github.com/445874/2a4b0bb0bde29485fec1ad1a5bbf968df80f2905

Comment: let's hope for that in Scala 2.9 ?

Answer (score 6):

To add a `toRandomClass` you'd have to resort to a pimp my library pattern indeed. However, why do you think that is overkill? The overhead is negligible. And it *wouldn't* work extending an utility class -- why would Scala look into your new class for that method? Not to mention that you'd have to instantiate such a class to be able to access its methods.

Answer (score 5):

There is no circular dependency here.
Circular dependency is what happens when there are a few independent components which refer to each other.
Scala standard library is one component. Since it is built always in one step there is no problem.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a little odd to consider such intricate and complex aggregate as Scala's Library an atomic entity? Cyclic Dependency could manifest in any level of bordering between the components. You are basically erasing the question by making it "Internal Details" of something which is not the area of interest. He is asking exactly about that internal details :-)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency

Answer (score 3):

You are right. Let's remove `toString` from the `String` class...